# Outputting validation error correctly : Django

Tags: django

The below code validates the email address provided and shows up a message if the email address is invalid.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True)
    username = models.TextField(unique=True, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(null=True)
    
    #avatar = models.ImageField(null=True, default="avatar.svg")
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

```
from django.core.validators import validate_email   
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
```

```
is_valid = validate_email(user.email)
        try:
            if is_valid == True:
                password1 = request.POST.get('txtPassword')
                password2 = request.POST.get('txtConfPassword')
        except ValidationError:
            messages.error(request, "Email address is invalid...")
```

I want this validation error displayed in the form and the user needs to stay in the form, but unfortunately it gets redirected to the errro page

```
ValidationError at /register/
['Enter a valid email address.']
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/
Django Version: 4.2.5
Exception Type: ValidationError
Exception Value:    
['Enter a valid email address.']
Exception Location: E:\theparams\theparamsenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\validators.py, line 210, in __call__
Raised during:  theparams.views.registerPage
Python Executable:  E:\theparams\theparamsenv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.11.4
Python Path:    
['E:\\theparams',
 'C:\\Users\\Win\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\python311.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Win\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Win\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Win\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311',
 'E:\\theparams\\theparamsenv',
 'E:\\theparams\\theparamsenv\\Lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 29 Sep 2023 11:10:10 +0000
```

Comment: Where have you placed the validation logic? Is it in a view?

Comment: Yes.. it is inside the view file. The form I am using is a custom form that I created using raw HTML

Comment: Are you using the builtin `User` model? Or you created your own?

Comment: The User model I am using is extension of AbstractUser class.

Comment: Can you edit the question and include the `models.py` file.

Comment: I have edited and added the models.py

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing things up. What happens when `!is_valid` ? Also provide full code not just a section of it. Try this:

```py
from django.core.validators import validate_email   

       if validate_email(user.email):
            password1 = request.POST.get('txtPassword')
            password2 = request.POST.get('txtConfPassword')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Email address is invalid...")
```

Comment: I am not checking form.isvalid().. I am just capturing the values from POST and I am doing my own validation